# localhost cron issue, log shows the cmd ran but the script actually did not start.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

First the important bits:

crontab -e

```
*/5 * * * * root etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh && curl -sm 30 k.wdt.io/bhart@domain.com/check_davmail?c=*/5_*_*_*_*
```

davmail_check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(pgrep -f davmail.jar | wc -w)
if [ $count = 0 ]; then
echo "Starting Davmail:        $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
/home/bhart/Downloads/davmail-linux-x86_64-4.8.0-2479/davmail.sh &
elif [ $count != 1 ]; then
echo "Restarted Davmail:        $(date)" >> /var/log/davmail.txt
kill $(ps aux | grep 'davmail' | awk '{print $2}')
fi
```

/var/log/cron  file:

```
Aug 29 15:55:01 Vostok CROND[27795]: (bhart) CMD (root etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh && curl -sm 30 k.wdt.io/bhart@egovmt.com/check_davmail?c=*/5_*_*_*_*)
```

If I manually run the davmail_check.sh it will correctly start davmail. What is wrong with the cron job?

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit

```
*/5 * * * * root etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh && curl -sm 30 k.wdt.io/bhart@domain.com/check_davmail?c=*/5_*_*_*_*
```

to

```
*/5 * * * * root /etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh && curl -sm 30 'k.wdt.io/bhart@domain.com/check_davmail?c=*/5_*_*_*_*'
```

You forgot a `/` and your URL needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested.. the 5 minute timer hit and got this entry is the log:
    `Aug 29 16:15:01 Vostok CROND[29735]: (bhart) CMD (root /etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh && curl -sm 30 'k.wdt.io/bhart@domain.com/check_davmail?c=*/5_*_*_*_*')`

Comment: removed the k.wdt.io part for now.

Comment: So another5 minutes.  another entry in /var/log/cron but the process never started.  Where else can I look to help determine whats going on?
`Aug 29 16:20:01 Vostok CROND[30275]: (bhart) CMD (root /etc/cron.d/check_davmail.sh)`

Comment: Anyone else?  Hunter? This bloody script still won't start davmail for me except when ran manually.